# Can I shift Amazon Athena SQL data by one column to the previous column if the value is NULL

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I'm trying to run the query on Amazon Athena. 
There are a total of 10 columns, but for the example has four columns 
For example:

| customer | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | NULL | B | C |
| 02 | NULL | NULL | A | B |
| 03 | NULL | A | NULL | B |

To:

| customer | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01 | A | B | C | NULL |
| 02 | A | B | NULL | NULL |
| 03 | A | B | NULL | NULL |

I tried to use several other SQL codes I found online but they couldn't be used on Amazon Athena

Comment: why would you want to do that? you'd be destroying the relation of your data

Comment: it so happens that they are the similar columns (e.g. Type A, Type B, ...) and there are null values in between which I want to eliminate

Answer (score 0):

One option would be:

1. Use concat_ws() on all the columns with comma as a separator.  This will concat the columns with a specified separator and nulls get thrown out.

> concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)

2. Then use split_part(), splitting on that comma for each of the columns. For Col1 that would be:

> split_part(concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4),
> ',', 1)

Working example:

```
select customer,
    split_part(concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4), ',', 1) as Col1,
    split_part(concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4), ',', 2) as Col2,
    split_part(concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4), ',', 3) as Col3,
    split_part(concat_ws(',', Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4), ',', 4) as Col4
from (
        values('01', 'A', NULL, 'B', 'C'),
        ('02', NULL, NULL, 'A', 'B'),
        ('03', NULL, 'A', NULL, 'B')
    ) as test_date(customer, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)
```

Giving results of:

[image]